# Limit Involving Factorials

Tags: limits, factorial, infinity

How would you go about calculating

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x!}{(x - k)!}
$$

for some constant $k > 0$?

Comment: Stirling approximation.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{x!}{(x-k)!} = (x-k+1)*(x-k+2)*...*(x-1)*x$

Answer (score 0):

Take upper and lower bounds:
$$
(x-k+1)^k \leq x(x-1) \ldots (x-k+1) \leq x^k
$$
and apply squeeze lemma. What do you get?